# Tensorflow dequeue is very slow on Cloud ML

Tags: performance, tensorflow, queue, pipeline, google-cloud-ml

I am trying to run a CNN on the cloud (Google Cloud ML) because my laptop does not have a GPU card.

So I uploaded my data on Google Cloud Storage. A .csv file with 1500 entries, like so:

```
    | label  |  img_path  |
    | label_1| /img_1.jpg |
    | label_2| /img_2.jpg |
```

and the corresponding 1500 jpgs.

My input_fn looks like so:

```
def input_fn(filename,
         batch_size,
         num_epochs=None,
         skip_header_lines=1,
         shuffle=False):
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filename, num_epochs=num_epochs)
reader = tf.TextLineReader(skip_header_lines=skip_header_lines)
_, row = reader.read(filename_queue)
row = parse_csv(row)
pt = row.pop(-1)
pth = filename.rpartition('/')[0] + pt
img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(tf.read_file(tf.squeeze(pth)), 1)
img = tf.to_float(img) / 255.
img = tf.reshape(img, [IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1])
row = tf.concat(row, 0)
if shuffle:
    return tf.train.shuffle_batch(
        [img, row],
        batch_size,
        capacity=2000,
        min_after_dequeue=2 * batch_size + 1,
        num_threads=multiprocessing.cpu_count(),
    )
else:
    return tf.train.batch([img, row],
                          batch_size,
                          allow_smaller_final_batch=True,
                          num_threads=multiprocessing.cpu_count())
```

Here is what the full graph looks like (very simple CNN indeed):
[image: Full graph]

Running the training with a batch size of 200, then most of the compute time on my laptop (on my laptop, the data is stored locally) is spent on the gradients node which is what I would expect. The batch node has a compute time of ~12ms.

When I run it on the cloud (scale-tier is BASIC), the batch node takes more than 20s. And the bottleneck seems to be coming from the QueueDequeueUpToV2 subnode according to tensorboard:

[image: Inside the batch node, QueueDequeueUpToV2]

Anyone has any clue why this happens? I am pretty sure I am getting something wrong here, so I'd be happy to learn.

Few remarks:
-Changing between batch/shuffle_batch with different min_after_dequeue does not affect.
-When using BASIC_GPU, the batch node is also on the CPU which is normal according to what I read and it takes roughly 13s. 
-Adding a time.sleep after queues are started to ensure no starvation also has no effect.
-Compute time is indeed linear in batch_size, so with a batch_size of 50, the compute time would be 4 times smaller than with a batch_size of 200.

Thanks for reading and would be happy to give more details if anyone needs.

Best,
Al

**Update:**

-Cloud ML instance and Buckets were not in the same region, making them in the same region improved result 4x.

-Creating a .tfrecords file made the batching take 70ms which seems to be acceptable. I used this [blog](http://warmspringwinds.github.io/tensorflow/tf-slim/2016/12/21/tfrecords-guide/) post as a starting point to learn about it, I recommend it.

I hope this will help others to create a fast data input pipeline!

Comment: perhaps copy the data to local disk first?

Comment: You mean from cloud storage to the cloud ml instance?

Comment: Expanding on Yaroslav's comment, you could try running your code on your laptop, but reading files from GCS. That should be more inline with what you see in the cloud. If you don't have a lot of data, then you can do what Yaro says and at the beginning of your script, copy the files locally.

Comment: It might be worth checking that the GCS bucket with the training data is in the same Google Cloud region where you're running the Cloud ML Engine training job.

Comment: Thanks Alexey, indeed Yaro's comment made have a look at it and reduced the batch compute time to 2-3 seconds. A lot better, but still looks like a lot compared to say the gradients computation. I will try to copy the data locally to see if that makes any more improvements.

Comment: Ok so regarding Yaroslav and rhartel80 comments, if I read files from GCS and run locally, the batch node takes 20 seconds on my laptop. So it seems like the code is fine, but the problem is the distance between cloud storage and the ml instance.

Copying locally the data does not really seem like a good solution is it? If I train my model on a BASIC_GPU instance, the whole time is being spent on that batch node. So what is commonly done? I assume people have their data on GCS, but I might be wrong?

Comment: The TensorFlow ImageNet performance [benchmarks](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/benchmarks#methodology) say they used "1.7 TB Shared SSD persistent disk (800 MB/s)" for data. Not familiar with GCS, maybe @rhaertel80 or  Alexey Surkov knows what this corresponds to

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, the way to go was making sure the regions matched and using TFRecords. Updated my post so it can help others. Thanks for the good work, keep it up, love using TF! :)

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working. FTR, CloudML does not currently support persistent disk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try converting your images to tfrecord format and read them directly from graph. The way you are doing it, there is no possibility of caching and if your images are small, you are not taking advantage of the high sustained reads from cloud storage. Saving all your jpg images into a tfrecord file or small number of files will help.

Also, make sure your bucket is a single region bucket in a region that had gpus and that you are submitting to cloudml in that region.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the similar problem before. I solved it by changing tf.train.batch() to tf.train.batch_join(). In my experiment, with 64 batch size and 4 GPUs, it took 22 mins by using tf.train.batch() whilst it only took 2 mins by using tf.train.batch_join().

In Tensorflow doc:

If you need more parallelism or shuffling of examples between files, use multiple reader instances using the tf.train.shuffle_batch_join

https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data